# Static route without knowing the nexthop (linux)

Tags: linux, networking, routing, bridge, iproute2

I have an **eth3** interface in a linux router, with an adsl modem. This adsl modem is in **bridged mode**, so the public IP is assigned to eth3 (say 11.22.33.44), and the modem is just not seen by my server.

I want to define a **static route** to a specific IP (88.191.250.176) through eth3, but I don't have a nexthop to set:

```
ip route add 88.191.250.176 dev eth3
```

is accepted but *does not work* (packets never make their way out).

```
ip route add 88.191.250.176 via 11.22.33.44 dev eth3
```

*Does not work* either.

If I set the modem in router mode, then I have a NATed address for the linux server (192.168.1.2), and IP address for the Adsl router (192.168.1.1), and I can do:

```
ip route add 88.191.250.176 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth3
```

Does work.

Is it possible to define a static route through my adsl modem in **bridged** mode (first case), without having an explicit nexthop to give ?

Comment: What is the IP of the interface?  Is it static or what?  When your ISP gave you the static, didn't they also give you the gateway?  You need the gateway address.  Using the device name as a route target mostly only works on serial links.

Comment: Zoredache: you're right and you have enlightened me and my understanding of network configuration. Wish I could promote your comment as answer, as it really was what I was looking for. Now I have found the gateway address and can use it a 'via' parameter. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The traffic has to go via your ISP's gateway. If eth3 has been assigned your public IP, then the default gateway address should be listed in your routing table:

```
ip route show table main
```

You then need to issue

```
ip route add 88.191.250.176 via <gatewayip> dev eth3
```

It should then work.